# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'assign' | Dataframe Python using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, assign

I am trying to access data using web-scraping and making it into a data frame using pandas. With the following code, I am already able to get the data frame. I want to combine all the data frames with append into one large data frame.

```
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import unquote
from json import loads
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Download URL
url = "https://riwayat-file-covid-19-dki-jakarta-jakartagis.hub.arcgis.com/"
req = requests.get(url)

# Get encoded JSON from HTML source
encoded_data = re.search("window\.__SITE=\"(.*)\"", req.text).groups()[0]

# Decode and load as dictionary
json_data = loads(unquote(encoded_data))

# Get the HTML source code for the links
html_src = json_data["site"]["data"]["values"]["layout"]["sections"][1]["rows"][0]["cards"][0]["component"]["settings"]["markdown"]

# Parse it using BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_src, 'html.parser')

# Get links
links = soup.find_all('a')

# For each link...
link_list = []
id_list = []
date_list = []
dataframe_csv = []

for link in links:
    if "2021" in link.text:
       link_list.append(link.text+" - "+link.attrs['href'])

link_list.remove("31 Januari 2021 Pukul 10.00 - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vd1tToQbx3A420KMDA63aKviLjgGPJMd/view?usp=sharing")

for i in link_list:
    id_list.append(i.split("/")[5])
    date_list.append(i.split("/")[0][:-21])
    
for ID in id_list:
    dataframe_csv.append("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ID+"/export?format=csv")
```

I want to combine all the data frames that I have by using a loop. For every loop, I want to remove the index 0 row and add a new column which is Date. The code is as follows:

```
date_num = 0
df_total = pd.DataFrame()

for i in dataframe_csv:
    df = pd.read_csv(i)
    df = df.drop(index=df.index[0], axis=0, inplace=True)
    df = df.assign(Date = date_list[date_num])
    
    date_num += 1
    
    df_total.append(df,ignore_index=True)
```

The problem is, I get an error like this:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-ef67f0a87a8e> in <module>
      5     df = pd.read_csv(i)
      6     df = df.drop(index=df.index[0], axis=0, inplace=True)
----> 7     df = df.assign(Date = date_list[date_num])
      8 
      9     date_num += 1

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'assign'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inplace=True` modifies the dataframe directly, so either remove it:

```
date_num = 0
df_total = pd.DataFrame()

for i in dataframe_csv:
    df = pd.read_csv(i)
    df = df.drop(index=df.index[0], axis=0)
    df = df.assign(Date = date_list[date_num])
    
    date_num += 1
    
    df_total.append(df,ignore_index=True)
```

Or not assign it back:

```
date_num = 0
df_total = pd.DataFrame()

for i in dataframe_csv:
    df = pd.read_csv(i)
    df.drop(index=df.index[0], axis=0, inplace=True)
    df = df.assign(Date = date_list[date_num])
    
    date_num += 1
    
    df_total.append(df,ignore_index=True)
```

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) of `drop`:

> ***inplace : bool, default False***
>
>      If False, return a copy. Otherwise, do operation inplace and return None.

Comment: +Docs for reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html "inplacebool, default False
If False, return a copy. Otherwise, do operation inplace and return None." :)

Comment: @h4z3 Added it in :)

Comment: I tried deleting "inplace = True", and now there is no more error. But, the data frame "df_total" has no value inside it. I tried df_total.shape and it returns (0,0) meaning the dataframe is still empty.

Comment: @ChristianEvanBudiawan That's problems with other stuff in your code, I solved your current problem.